# UIScrollView change subview position

Tags: objective-c, dynamic, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` that is resized depending on the context. My subviews are also repositioned based on the context.

When it loads, everything goes fine. But, when I touch the scrollview, all my subviews go back to their original position.

That messes up my layout.

I already specified:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

Without any good result.

Does someone know why?

Here is the code where I position the subview and resize the scrollview.
The `btnSave` button goes back to it's original position when I scroll.

```
float more = 0;
float height = 900;

if (IS_IPHONE_6) {
    height = 1050;
} else if (IS_IPHONE_6P) {
    more = 200;
    height = 1100;
}

status = [AVCaptureDevice authorizationStatusForMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

if (appDelegate.driverFisrtName != nil && ![appDelegate.driverPlateImage isEqualToString:@""]) {
    height = 1300;
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, height);
    self.btnSave.frame = CGRectMake(self.btnSave.frame.origin.x,
                                    self.btnSave.frame.origin.y - more,
                                    self.btnSave.frame.size.width,
                                    self.btnSave.frame.size.height);
} else {
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, height);
}
```

Comment: not getting your issue properly ? what you want exactly ?

Comment: @KetanParmar When I start the application, subviews the btnSave is at position x:100 y:200. After the user click the btnSave button, it move to x:300 y:100. After that, when the user scroll down or up, the btnSave goes back to x:100 y:200. This is not the behavior that I want. I don't know why the scroll event brings the btnSave to it's original position.